# Laravel validator returning empty error messages

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I am validating a form in `Laravel` but I am not getting empty error messages.

```
$validator = Validator::make($all, [
                    'email' => 'required|email',
                    'email_confirmation' => 'required',
                    'first_name' => 'required',
                    'last_name' => 'required',
                    'gender' => 'required',
                    'year' => 'required',
                    'month' => 'required',
                    'day' => 'required',
                    'birth_country' => 'required',
                    'birth_city' => 'required',
                    'native_country' => 'required',
                    'password' => 'required',
                    'password_confirmation' => 'required',
                    'address' => 'required',
                    'country' => 'required',
                    'region' => 'required',
                    'city' => 'required',
                    'tel_area_code' => 'required',
                    'tel_number' => 'required',
                    'postal_code' => 'required',
                    'mobile_area_code' => 'required',
                    'mobile_number' => 'required',
                    'terms_cond_check' => 'required',
                ],[
                    'terms_cond_check.required' => 'You must agree to our Terms and Conditions',
                ]);
```

The response is

```
MessageBag {#568 ▼
  #messages: array:10 [▼
    "password" => array:1 [▼
      0 => ""
    ]
    "password_confirmation" => array:1 [▼
      0 => ""
    ]
    "address" => array:1 [▼
      0 => ""
    ]
    "region" => array:1 [▼
      0 => ""
    ]
    "city" => array:1 [▼
      0 => ""
    ]
    "tel_area_code" => array:1 [▼
      0 => ""
    ]
    "tel_number" => array:1 [▼
      0 => ""
    ]
    "postal_code" => array:1 [▼
      0 => ""
    ]
    "mobile_area_code" => array:1 [▼
      0 => ""
    ]
    "mobile_number" => array:1 [▼
      0 => ""
    ]
  ]
  #format: ":message"
}
```

Comment: Can you show your form ?

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to redirect in the form view. I mean add this 
after your validation

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect(route('tape here your form route (you can find that in route/web.php)'))
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }
```

after that you need to show all error message in the form view.

just add this on the top of your form view page to show all error message :

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
   <ul>
       @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
          <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: u need to replace $all by $request->all(); in you validator::make method